# Multiple instructions after "?" operator

Tags: c++

I have to do a fraction `struct`, already got `nominator` and `denominator` and `is_correct()` function, which checks two necessary conditions. But now I have to make a `shorten()` function which would make my fraction irreducible.

I'v made a `gcd()` function (greatest common divisor) and I need to put a `shorten()` function in my structure. It looks like this:

```
struct fraction {
                int n,d;
                bool is_correct(){return d!=0?(abs(n)<abs(d)?true:false):false;};
                void shorten(){gcd(n,d)!=1?(n=n/gcd(n,d);d=d/gcd(n,d)):;};
                }; 

int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int z;
    while (y!=0){z=x%y;x=y;y=z;}
    return x;
}
```

So if `gcd()` returns not `1` value, then I want to divide `n` by this value and divide `d` by this value.

And when I try to make it gives me expected ":" before ";" token in many places. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just write it out `if`/`else...` instead of doing too much with `?` (while it can make code shorter, it can also make code less readable).

Comment: Does that code look easy to read and understand to you?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide an expression to the `:` part of the `?:` operator. You should use `if` statement instead of ternary operator like this:

```
int g = gcd(n, d);
if (g != 1)
{
    n = n / g;
    d = d / g;
}
```

Comment: And what if I have to `gcd()` negative numbers? Wouldn't it mess up a bit?

Comment: You should be using the absolute value as the return from your gcd function. You may still need to deal with both numerator and denominator being negative, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I believe there should be a check for denominator equal to zero.  Dividing by 1 is only a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

By formatting your code correctly, you would spot the error:

`void shorten(){gcd(n,d)!=1?(n=n/gcd(n,d);d=d/gcd(n,d)):;};`

is

```
void shorten() { gcd(n, d) != 1 ? (n = n / gcd(n, d) ; d = d / gcd (n , d)):; };
                                                   ^^^^^^                     ^^
                                             missing                     colon should be  
                                             paranthesis/                in between the 
                                             semicolon doesn't           statements
                                             belong here
```

So you would write it as:

```
void shorten() { gcd(n, d) != 1 ? (n /= gcd(n, d)) : (d /= gcd(n, d)); }
```

or even better

```
void shorten()
{
    if (gcd(n, d) != 1)
        n /= gcd(n, d);
    else
        d /= gcd(n, d);
}
```